# Ckeditor throws errors , uncaught reference error and uncaught type error , how to resolve it?

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery for ckeditor which throws 2 exceptions.
I have also included the js files within the script tag.

Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined ck_editor.js:15

Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined jquery.js:5

form.html

```
<script src="js/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<div align="right" class="ckeditor">
        <textarea id="ck_texteditor"></textarea>
</div>
```

ck_editor.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var config = {
        height : 280,
        width : 1000,
        fullPage : true,
        linkShowAdvancedTab : false,
        scayt_autoStartup : true,
        enterMode : Number(2),
        toolbar : [
                [ 'Styles','Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 
                        'NumberedList',
                        'BulletedList', 'SpellChecker', '-', 'Undo',
                        'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'NumberedList',
                        'BulletedList','FontSize' ], [ 'UIColor' ] ]
    };
/****line no 15 **/ $("#ck_texteditor").ckeditor(config);
```

});

line no 15 is where the error comes , can anyone tell me what is the problem ?
Thank you

Comment: do u mean to say ckeditor.js file ??

Comment: *The `<script src="js/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` should be included after jQuery file.

Comment: Seems like 'enterMode' is different in your config.
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode

Answer (score 3):

You are missing to add ***jQuery adapter***. jQuery adapter is present in ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js

### View [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLmcekqs/1/)

> **What is jQuery Adapter?** - The jQuery Adapter allows for easy use of basic CKEditor functions and access to the internal API. [Read more](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery).

#### HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard-all/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<div align="right" class="ckeditor">
        <textarea id="ck_texteditor"></textarea>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var config = {
        height : 280,
        width : 1000,
        fullPage : true,
        linkShowAdvancedTab : false,
        scayt_autoStartup : true,
        enterMode : Number(2),
        toolbar : [
            ['Styles','Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 
             'NumberedList',
             'BulletedList', 'SpellChecker', '-', 'Undo',
             'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'NumberedList',
             'BulletedList','FontSize' ], [ 'UIColor' ] ]
    };
    $("#ck_texteditor").ckeditor(config);
});
```